# Algorithm for finding diversity of a sequence

Tags: algorithm

I think there should be an algorithm for this out there so I hope someone can help me out here.

I want to find out a metric that shows diversity in terms of number of unique numbers and transition between two consecutive elements of a given sequence. For example,

```
sequence-1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
sequence-2 = [1,1,1,1,2,2]
sequence-3 = [1,2,3,1,3,2]
sequence-4 = [2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

If I compare based on that metric, the result should look like as follows:

```
sequence-3 > sequence-1 > sequence-2 > sequence-4
```

Basically, the criteria getting that result may be something like:

```
transistion_changes for sequence-1: 2 (1->2, 2->3)
transistion_changes for sequence-2: 1 (1->2)
transistion_changes for sequence-3: 5 (1->2, 2->3, 3->1, 1->3, 3->2)
transistion_changes for sequence-4: 0
```

**Is there an algorithm in literature does the same thing?**

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: It seems to me that you **have** an algorithm, so I don't really see why finding it in literature or finding a similar algorithm would be useful, unless you see some problem with this algorithm, which you should mention.

Comment: There are a few different metrics for this... Do we know whether the sequences are bounded or finite?

Comment: @AlexReinking, no the sequences are not bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) if (sequence[i] != sequence[i - 1]) count++;
```

Right?

or something like

```
double count = 0.0;

for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    for (int k = 1; k < 3; k++) {
        if (i - k >= 0) {
            count += abs(sequence[i] - sequence[i - k]) / k;
        }
    }
}
```

For cases of:

- sequence { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 }, count == 0.0
- sequence { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 }, count == 5.0
- sequence { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, count == 9.0
- sequence { 1, 9, 2, 11, -3, 7 }, count == 53.0

Very basic metric but works.

Comment: He didn't handle the case in his example, but I doubt he wants to double count transitions. Surely [1,2,1,2,1,2] is less diverse than [1,2,3,4,5,6]?

Comment: I added a slightly more complicated algorithm. OP, it really depends on how you want to exactly define your diversity.

Comment: I think what i want is that in your example, count of sequence-3 should be equal to count of sequence-4 because both have same diversity.

Comment: Well if your only metric is != you can just as soon as change the evaluation to that. `if (sequence[i] != sequence[i - k]) count++;` in which case sequence 3 and sequence 4 both result in 15. You can also still factor in the distance between points as `count += 1 / k;` if you want to. The inner loop can also be the length of the sequence instead of 3 if you want to evaluate all of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

For that simple purpose, you may design a [FIR](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response) filter, and sum the result. That way should be similar to compute the energy in the high band of your signal.

Let's say:

```
y(n) = x(n) - 1/2 * x(n-1) + 1/3 * x(n-2)
```

Anyway, you should ask that question in another StackExchange site such as the one for maths.

Comment: This is true. You could also do this kind of thing with FFTs. It depends on what the OP wants the metric to be exactly.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? for example, what is the value of x(n) in my example?

Comment: It fully depends on the final purpose of that measurement, how typical input samples are, etc. If you explain us with more detail maybe we can recommend you what to do.

Comment: @CoKoder x(n) is the input sequence. x[] holds the array and n is the index on the current loop iteration. The output is a new filtered array y[].